# Prime number algorithm Objective C explanation please

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop, primes

Hi sorry for my bad english, i have a question guys, i'm learning objective c and i'm learning booleans right now, my question is: why when running the second loop in the code, the number 2 is taken as prime, i mean, as i see it p takes the value 2 in the first loop, then d start at 2 but then it says d < p, i think that's p-1 (2-1 = 1), so how that code works, it doesn't make sense, i understand why it works with any other number greater than 2 but i don't get it why it works with the number 2!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        int p, d;
        BOOL isPrime;

        for (p = 2; p <= 50; p++)
        {
            isPrime = true;

            for (d = 2; d < p; d++)
            {
                if (p % d == 0)
                isPrime = false;
            }

            if (isPrime == true)
                NSLog(@"%i", p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a single ongoing sentence, which is hard to read. Your problem isn't clear. Also, why have you tagged this question [tag:c] instead of [tag:objective-c]?

Comment: I don't get you. Where are p-1 istruction?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stack overflow, i just want to know why the loop takes 2 as a prime number if in the second loop the for starts at 2 but ends at 1, and in that case the two remainders of p % d are 0, i'm a bit confused about that.

Comment: No, i don't have a p-1 instruction, i'm just saying that d < p is like p-1

Comment: It is simply C. Nothing Objective-C in this.

Comment: Quick note: when you find that the number is not prime you can break out of the inner loop (you don't need to test any more numbers). Also you don't need to check any values greater than the square root of the number you're testing for prime. You may also take advantage of two being the only even prime number by incrementing p by 2 (when greater than 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop starts p=2, then the inner loop take `d=2` and then check if `d<p`. This condition is **false** because `d=2 P=2`. This means the first inner loop doesn't run and isPrime is always **true** at the first loop of p.

Comment: Man that explains everything! Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

A prime number is divisible by 1 or itself. 
So we check divisibility for all the numbers between 1 and the number.

That is why we start we 2 and till number-1

```
for(d = 2; d < p; d++ )
```

Comment: what is p here? is it the number?

Comment: the max value of the range to check prime

Answer (score 0):

```
Prime numbers are the numbers which are not divisible by any other number.They are divisible by itself only (eg 2,3,5,7)
```

If we will only check till the half of number, since more than half of number will not divide it.

```
-(BOOL)checkNumberPrimeNumber:(int)number{

        int i; BOOL flag=false;

        for (i=2; i<number/2; i++) {
            if (number%i==0) {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag==true) {
            NSLog(@"%d is Not Prime Number",number);

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%d is Prime Number",number);
        }

        return YES;
    }
```